# Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions (MongoDB/MongoHQ)

Tags: node.js, session, coffeescript, mongohq, ttl

I'm able to connect to my primary DB no problem, but when I try to connect to my replica set, I get the TTL error. I've done my best to include all relevant code examples, but please ask if you need to see something that's not included. This is driving me bananas. The DB is at mongoHQ.

#### So, the issue:

- I can connect to my primary set (workingDB)
- I cannot connect to my replica set (failingDB)
- I cannot connect when trying to connect to both(mongoHQ).

#### Code example

```coffee
mongoHQ = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@candidate
.14.mongolayer.com:10120/dbName,mongodb://<user>:<password>@candidate
.15.mongolayer.com:10120"

failingDB = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@candidate
.14.mongolayer.com:10120/dbName"

workingDB = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@candidate
.15.mongolayer.com:10120/dbName"


# DB Options
opts =
  mongos: true
  server:
    auto_reconnect: true

# Connect to DB
mongoose.connect mongoHQ, opts


# express/mongo session storage
app.use express.session(
  secret: "Secrets are for children"
  cookie:
    maxAge: process.env.SESSION_TTL * 3600000
    httpOnly: false
  store: new mongoStore(
    url: mongoHQ
    collection: "sessions"
  , ->
    console.log "We're connected to the session store"
    return
  )
)

# Error: Error setting TTL index on collection : sessions

# * Connecting to "workingDB" works as expected.
# * Connecting to "failingDB" throws the same TTL Error
# * candidate.14 is the primary set, candidate.15 is the replica set
```

Comment: Which module did you use for the MongoStore?  Did you get this working?  Thanks

Comment: Hey @JasonGelinas,

I was able to resolve the issue by simply removing the reference to the replica set in the URI. See my answer below.

Comment: @JasonGelinas and I was using connect-mongo for the mongoStore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by simply removing the reference to the replica set in the URI

```
mongoHQ = "mongodb://<user>:<password>@candidate.15.mongolayer.com:10120/dbName";
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit late, but I was today getting similar errors with MongoHQ and Mongoose. I solved it by removing the option `mongos: true` (at least for the moment, fingers crossed). I think that option is not really needed for replica sets (only when using mongos servers):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#replicaset_connections

http://support.mongohq.com/languages/mongoose.html

Also, it's better to wait for the connection being established before trying to set up MongoStore, for example:

```
mongoose.connect(mongoHQ);
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function () {
  // Panic
});

db.on('connected', function() {
    var app = express();
    app.use(express.session(sessionOptions));
    // etc...
    app.listen(config.port, function() {
        console.log('Listening on port ', config.port);
    });
});
```